# I am completely new to using ajax with django. How do I write the function for ajax for changing the value of model field?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I am using CBVs and I need to change the value of a field on button click.  I have tried some code but it doesn't seem to work. What is wrong in this code and what can be modified?

script

```
 $("#ajax_button").on('click', function () {

  $.ajax({
    url: 'NewApp/ajax/change_status/{{userprofile.id}}',
    data: {

      'verified': False ,

    },
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend:function(){
     return confirm("Are you sure?");
    success: function (data) {
      if (data.success) {
        alert("ajax call success.");
        // here you update the HTML to change the active to inactive
      }else{
        alert("ajax call not success.");
      }
    }
  });

});
```

views.py

```
 def ajax_change_status(request,pk):
userpr = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=pk)

try:
    userpr.verified = True
    userpr.save()
    return JsonResponse({"success": True})
except Exception as e:
    return JsonResponse({"success": False})
return JsonResponse(data)
```

urls.py

```
 url(r'^ajax/change_status/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ajax_change_status, name='ajax_verified')
```

Comment: `it doesn't seem to work` - read the logs, check browser console output and HTTP response status, stop hiding error message by this horrible try-except and update your question with actual error message.

Comment: The function is not being called on button click itself so I cannot post the errors.

Comment: Which function? JS?

Comment: I tried putting an alert inside the js function and it worked. The problem seems to be in ajax.

Comment: **What problem**? What exactly is happening? You have a call to `confirm()` in the `beforeSend` function, which is odd; but is that confirmation box being displayed?

Comment: No. Nothing inside ajax is getting displayed. I tried using JS instead of jQuery and the function returned alert, but with jquery, nothing works.

Comment: Does the browser console contain `$ is not defined` line?

Comment: No. The console simply doesn't return anything.